# Saving scraped documents in two sheets in an excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, web-scraping, pyexcel

I've created a scraper which is supposed to parse some documents from a webpage and save it to an excel file creating two sheets. However, when I run it, I can see that It only saves the documents of last link in a single sheet whereas there should be two sheets with documents from two links properly. I even printed the results to see what is happening in the background but i found there nothing wrong. I thing the first sheet is overwritten and second one is never created. How to get around this so that data will be saved in two sheets in an excel file. Thanks in advance to take a look into it.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data

name_list = ['Altronix','APC']

def docs_parser(link, name):   
    res = requests.get(link)
    root = html.fromstring(res.text)
    vault = {}
    for post in root.cssselect(".SubBrandList a"):
        if post.text == name:
            refining_docs(post.attrib['href'], vault)

def refining_docs(new_link, vault):
    res = requests.get(new_link).text
    root = html.fromstring(res)  
    sheet = root.cssselect("#BrandContent h2")[0].text   
    for elem in root.cssselect(".ProductDetails"):
        name_url = elem.cssselect("a[class]")[0].attrib['href']
        vault.setdefault(sheet, []).append([str(name_url)])
        save_data("docs.ods", vault)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for name in name_list:
        docs_parser("http://store.immediasys.com/brands/" , name)
```

But, the same way when I write code for another site, it meets the expectation creating different sheets and saving documents in those. Here is the link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgyh1xxhew8hcvm/Pyexcel_so.txt?dl=0

Comment: `save_data(...` must be called only **once** as last Statement inside `__main__`.

Comment: Thanks stovfl, for your suggestion. The way you have said solves the issue. However, follow the link I've pasted above where I have written code for another site and I found nothing wrong with the results there. I never used the "save_data" parameter within the "main" statement either. Why is the difference? Btw, please provide it as an answer because your suggestion rocks.

Comment: Linked code is much different than code here. So your process is different and hence difference in saving file. Likely it is the shape/format of data being scrapped.

Comment: How can the linked code be much different? I didn't find any logic in your statement. Shape, format etc have got nothing to do with not creating any separate sheets until javascript is enabled there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: I thing the first sheet is overwritten and second one is never created. How to get around this so that data will be saved in two sheets in an excel file.

You overwrite the Workbook File on **every** Link that's be appended.
You should **never** call `save_data(...` within a loop, only **once** at the End of your Script.

Comparing you Two Scripts there is **No** difference, both behave the same, again and again overwriting the Workbook File. Maybe the File IO get overloaded as you doing more than **160** Times overwriting the Workbook File within a short Time.

The First Script should create **13** Sheets:

```
data sheet:powerpivot-etc links:20
data sheet:flappy-owl-videos links:1
data sheet:reporting-services-videos links:20
data sheet:csharp links:14
data sheet:excel-videos links:9
data sheet:excel-vba-videos links:20
data sheet:sql-server-videos links:9
data sheet:report-builder-2016-videos links:4
data sheet:ssrs-2016-videos links:5
data sheet:sql-videos links:20
data sheet:integration-services links:19
data sheet:excel-vba-user-form links:20
data sheet:archived-videos links:16
```

The Second Script should create **2** Sheets:

```
vault sheet:Altronix links:16
vault sheet:APC links:16
```

Comment: Thanks stovfl, for your answer. I can understand now how the data are getting scraped. However, I've erected my question because second script is not following the logic as you said in your answer as well. Calling "save_data" within "main" statement works, though! You explained the mechanism how it should work but forgot to mention why the second script behaves differently, as in It creates only one sheet instead of two.

Comment: @Topto: I have tested your both Scripts, I found **no** differences. The explanation why only the Last Sheet is found in the Workbook File is due to on every `save_data(...` the Dict `data/vault` is cleared.

Comment: Thanks stovfl for everything. I was not around my pc so got delayed to respond.